# Formatting number var with two decimal places

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code with two variables:

```
eventTotal = eventTotal + parseFloat(currentElement.title).toFixed(2);

deliveryTotal = deliveryTotal + parseFloat(currentElement.title).toFixed(2);
```

Whenever i add the variables together using:

```
totalbox.value = "£" + eventTotal + deliveryTotal;
```

The output is generally something like "£055.0003.99".

Why is this number not formatting  properly and how can i achieve this?

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string, so you're just concatenating strings. Get the total and then call `toFixed` on the result.

Comment: Bear in mind [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toFixed` returns a string, not a number. So in order to do addition and not concatenation (with `+`), you'll have to cast the value back to number:

```
totalbox.value = "£" + (parseFloat(eventTotal) + parseFloat(deliveryTotal)).toFixed(2);
```

**FWIW:** Instead you may use prefixed `+` as sort of a shortcut of `parseFloat`:

```
totalbox.value = "£" + (+eventTotal + +deliveryTotal).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has pointed out the issue, caused by `.toFixed()` returning a string, but all of those repeated calls to `parseFloat()`, `toFixed()` and casting are a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

It would be better to keep all of your variables as numbers and just pass them through a function to format to a human readable currency.

```
// convert to currency
function currencyFormat(amount){
    return '&pound;' + (amount*1).toFixed(2);
}

// cast to a number in one place
eventTotal =  eventTotal*1;
deliveryTotal = deliveryTotal*1;

// now work with the variables however you need, knowing that you always have numbers

// output currency
totalbox.value = currencyFormat(eventTotal + deliveryTotal);
eventbox.value = currencyFormat(eventTotal);
```

Now if you need to change the currency symbol or you want to change the decimal separator, or number of decimal places, it's one change in your *reusable code*. Also, you should use the HTML entity `&pound;` instead of using the raw symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Get the total and use

toFixed(2);

```
eventTotal = (eventTotal + parseFloat(currentElement.title)).toFixed(2);

deliveryTotal = (deliveryTotal + parseFloat(currentElement.title)).toFixed(2);
```